# Publicar automaticamente no Twitter a partir do site PHP

Tags: php, twitter-api

Estou a desenvolver um *backoffice* em PHP. E cada vez que o administrador adicionar um produto, esse produto vai ser publicado automaticamente no Twitter.

No Twitter vai aparecer:

- o nome do produto
- a sua imagem
- e o link para o site

Tive que fazer o mesmo para o Facebook, e até aí tudo bem. Agora estou a tentar para o Twitter e estou com dificuldades.

Quais são os passos básicos para o uso da API do Twitter?

Comment: Pode parecer ampla de mais, mas para quem esta a iniciar pode ser uma boa ajuda uma boa resposta

Comment: A meu ver, ele precisa de um pontapé inicial. O que é uma dúvida e a resposta pode ser bem simples como transcrever um pouco do https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update que é o tutorial que ele deseja

Comment: Tente explicar qual é a dificuldade, se tiver algum código edite a pergunta e coloque ele.

Comment: Discussão no META sobre essa pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1344/7210

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usando a **[RESTApi](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update)** do **Twitter** você deve executar uma ação de POST em `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json` com os seguintes parâmetros:

- **`status`** *exigido*
  O texto de sua atualização de status, normalmente até 140 caracteres. Fazer codificação de URL conforme necessário. [Encapsular com um link t.co](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq) pode afetar a contagem de caracteres.

  Existem alguns [comandos especiais](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14020-twitter-for-sms-basic-features) neste campo para os quais devemos estar cientes. Por exemplo, precedendo uma mensagem com "D" ou "M" e seguindo-a com um nome de tela pode criar uma mensagem direta para o usuário, se o relacionamento permitir isso.
- **`in_reply_to_status_id`** *opcional*
  O ID de um estado existente de que a atualização é em resposta a.

  Nota :: Este parâmetro será ignorado a menos que o autor do tweet que este parâmetro referencia seja mencionado no texto de status. Portanto, você deve incluir `@username`, onde `username` é o autor do seu tweet referenciado, dentro da atualização.
- **`lat`** *opcional*
  A latitude do local este tweet se refere. Esse parâmetro será ignorado, a menos que esteja dentro da faixa de -90,0 para 90,0 (Norte é positivo), inclusive. Também irá ser ignorado se não tem um parâmetro `long` correspondente.

  Valores de Exemplo: `37,7821120598956`
- **`long`** *opcional*
  A longitude da localização este tweet se refere. Os intervalos válidos para longitude é -180,0 a 180,0 (East é positivo), inclusive. Esse parâmetro será ignorado se fora desse intervalo, se não é um número, se `geo_enabled` está desativado, ou se não tem um parâmetro `lat` correspondente.

  Valores de Exemplo: `-122,400612831116`
- **`place_id`** *opcional*
  Um lugar no mundo. Essas identificações podem ser recuperados de GET `geo` / `reverse_geocode` .

  Valores de Exemplo: `df51dec6f4ee2b2c`
- **`display_coordinates`** *opcionais*
  Se deve ou não colocar um pino na coordenada exata de onde um tweet foi enviado.

  Valores de Exemplo: `true`
- **`trim_user`** *opcional*
  Quando definido como `true`, `t` ou `1`, cada tweet retornado na linha do tempo irá incluir um objeto de usuário incluindo apenas o ID numérico dos autores do status. Omita este parâmetro para receber o objeto de usuário completo.

  Valores de Exemplo: `true`